# "git push origin master" freezes

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my code to my Github account using the guidelines from the Git Help.
I tried both command-line and the GUI tool-GitExtension.
I am able to perform the initial steps successfully but when I do
"git push origin master" to push my code ,I get no response.
I dont think it should be a problem of SSH as I am not able to push it even when I use the 
"https" url as remote.

Comment: When you say you get no response, what do you mean? It literally just sits there and does nothing? How long have you let it wait? And I think it's implied, but you are using Windows?

Also, if you are in Windows, can you reproduce the issue using the copy of Git available in Cygwin?

Comment: can you pull with git:// url? https is readonly so it's normal. For me it's a SSH problem, check keys again

Comment: thanks it seems like my firewall is blocking the SSH connections.@TARehman - I am using windows 8.I will try it using Cygwin

Comment: (Of course, it is November, so hopefully you have this figured out...) If your firewall is blocking, using Cygwin won't help.  You can you push using the https link?  And https is not read only @CharlesB.  However, http is read only, and slow, but suitable for pulling repositories.  See [HTTP Cloning](https://github.com/blog/92-http-cloning).

@code4fun can you show your `git config --list` output?

Comment: @code4fun : Why dont you create an answer for this post and accept it ? I have visited this question thrice but found that it is already resolved. Wasted my time.

Comment: I currently have this issue as well, but I'm able to push to different repos on github. Any ideas as to what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments.The issue was that my firewall was blocking the SSH connections.

Comment: How did you solve the problem, could you add more details ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the installation may be with the latest version of Git. Reinstall git and while this option comes select the highlighted option as there in my screenshot.

Image:

[image]

This should work.

Thanks